# Python- Write a function that opens a .txt file and returns the total number of words in it

Tags: python, count, cpu-word

Been trying to do this for a while but for some reason i cant get my head around this simple code. Dont need to worry about punctuation, its just plain text. 
At the moment all i have is:

```
def wc(filename):

    f = open(filename, 'r')    # Read
    words = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    print int(filename.split())
    p = 1
    for word in words:
        p += words
    return p
```

been looking for an answer for a while but can only find examples where they count specific words.

Comment: You are splitting the filename, and converting the result (a list) into an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open(filename)    # Read
words = f.read()
f.close()
words = words.split()
print len(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) can take a parameter `sep` which specifies what characters to split on (the separator).

The string module has some constants including [`punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation) and [`whitespace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.whitespace).

Putting them together you get

```
import string

filename = 'words.txt'

with open(filename) as f:
    words = f.read().split(string.whitespace + string.punctuation)

print len(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one gives you lines

```
words = f.readlines()
```

You need to split word variable inside for via .split() method.

```
word_count += len(word.split())
```

Comment: `words` will be a list of strings.

Comment: yes, you are right. I just try to review and correct wrong part of code. It should be inside for and word.split()

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    words = f.read()
words = words.split(' ')
words_nbr = len(words)
print(words_nbr)
```